# session is coming null while updating records in database

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, session

I am working on normal update operation. I am getting session as null. Please find the below code in which i am getting exception and the logs.

Implementation class in spring -

```
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    Session session=null;

    private void assignSessionLocalVariable(){
        if(session == null || !session.isOpen()){
            try{
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            }catch(Exception e){session = null;
              logger.error("Stack trace ::"+e);
                logger.error("/### Session is null ####/");
            }
        }
    }
@Override
    public List<User> archieveUser(int userId) {
        assignSessionLocalVariable();
        User userIdDel = (User) session.get(User.class, userId);
        if(userIdDel.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("YES"))
            {   userIdDel.setStatus("NO");      }
        else{  userIdDel.setStatus("YES");  }
        
        logger.info("### object of the user ####"+userIdDel);
        try{    
            
                Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
                session.saveOrUpdate(userIdDel);
                tx.commit();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             logger.error("### Exception occured while archiveing USERS in IMPL #### ["+e+"] \n");
         }
        session.close();
        return new UserDAOImpl().getAllUser();
    }

public void closeSessionObjects(){
        if(null != session) session.clear();
        
    }
```

The log file -

> 2015-11-30 16:42:54 INFO  UserDAOImpl:74 - ### object of the user
>
> User [id=2 firstName Bharat lastName Bhushan creation_time 2015-11-30 16:19:24.0 last_update_time 2015-11-30 16:19:24.0 email
>
> bh@yahoo.com mobile 5800000 status YES] 2015-11-30 16:42:54 ERROR
> UserDAOImpl:30 - Stack trace ::java.lang.NullPointerException
> 2015-11-30 16:42:54 ERROR UserDAOImpl:31 - /### Session is null ####/

I am calling archiveUser() method and then getting the above log. If I use 'load' in place of 'get' then also same issue is coming.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logs aren't really consistent with the code and the course of action. If the session was not null when you got the user, it shouldn't be null couple of lines below.

`archiveUser()` probably finishes fine, but this is a problem

```
return new UserDAOImpl().getAllUser();
```

and it fails in another method, because `sessionFactory` is null.

When you instantiate the bean yourself, you are bypassing Spring and thus none of the Spring managed dependencies will get injected. If `getAllUser()` is in the same bean (as it looks), just change that line to

```
return getAllUser();
```

Comment: Oh!!, thanks, you are right. I just changed it and got the result. Thanks alot @Predrag Maric